# Apply migrations and models from all the apps in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-migrations

I'm using Django and I have an schema like this:

```
mainapp
|---mainapp
|   |---migrations.py
|   |---models/
|---app2
    |---migrations/
    |---models/
```

But, when I execute:

`python manage.py migrate` it is generationg the tables of `mainapp/models`, but no the `app2/models` and `app2/migrations` either.

How can execute those migrations?

Comment: Are there changes in the database of those apps as well?

Comment: @FazilZaid yes, are changes (tables to add)

Comment: Did you try python manage.py showmigrations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

first of all try

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

for a specific app

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname
```

this will migrate all the apps

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

hope it helps

Comment: I want a way of not specifying the app_name, where I migrate all apps once ?

Comment: yes, if you do not specify app_name all apps will get migrated @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris

Comment: But mine isn't doing so, until when I specify the app_name , what could be the issue  ?

Comment: whats the command u r running and whats the output it is providing, can u provide both

Comment: It has worked finally my bad. Thanks Exprator.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have added the app in the installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainapp',
    'app2',
    #......,
    #......,
]
```

Then create migrations

using `python mananage.py makemigrations` and migrate with `python manange.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

First to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-INSTALLED_APPS) in `settings.py`, you need to set all apps which you want to make migrations and migrate for as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app1',
    'app2'
]
```

Then, run the command below which can make migrations for all apps set in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then, run the command below which can migrate for all apps set in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

In addition, you can make migrations for specific multiple apps by specifying them as shown below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1 app2
```

But, if you specify the apps which are not set in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1 app2 app3 app4
```

Then, there are the errors below so no migrations are made for all the specified apps:

> No installed app with label 'app4'.
> No installed app with label 'app3'.

In addition, you can migrate for only one specific app by specifying it as shown below:

```
python manage.py migrate app1
```

But, you cannot migrate for multiple specific apps by specifying them as shown below:

```
python manage.py migrate app1 app2
```

Then, there is the error below:

> CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching 'app2' from app 'app1'.